# Convert Strings in Variables

Tags: evaluation, string-manipulation

I want to convert strings to variables. I want to create the term pionprodg1. I tried to do this:

```
particula ="pion";
ToExpression[particula <> "prodg1"]=MyTable1;
```

But there is a error:

Set::write: Tag ToExpression in ToExpression[pionprodg1] is Protected.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Look up "Symbol" in the help

Answer (score 5):

Try with this:

```
ToExpression[
    particula <> "prodg1",
    InputForm,
    Function[f, f = MyTable1, HoldAll]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The resource function [ConvertStringsToSymbols](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ConvertStringsToSymbols/) is useful for this, but you need to use `With` to evaluate the symbol names:

```
With[{
  sym = "pion" <> "prodg1"
  },
 ResourceFunction["ConvertStringsToSymbols"][sym = 1, sym]
]
```